# Lattice with snowflakes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lattice-model

Trying to understand these better.
I'm trying to find a conventional primitive unit mesh and find the planes of symmetry.
[image]

Now my attempt was simply finding the next points where it repeated itself.
[image]

It seems like a p4m to me, any opinions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I've missed some fine detail, the unit cell is:

[image: Unit cell]